# Loading new ViewController causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, uiwindow

I am trying to load a new UIViewController using a UIButton press method.

this is what the code looks like

```
- (void) getprojectButtonSelected {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

    currentProjectListViewController = [[CurrentProjectListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CurrentProjectListViewController" bundle:nil];

    UIWindow* keyWindow= [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [keyWindow addSubview: currentProjectListViewController.view];

    [self presentViewController:currentProjectListViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

I have added currentProjectListViewController in my .h file and am calling it here.. this is the line that fails also...

there is no error code only EXC_BAD_ACCESS

any help would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should take out the `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];`. There is no reason that should be there. You are supposed to use `dismissViewController` when you are trying to exit a modal segue. You did not have a current segue so it crashed. Glad it works now!

Comment: hrmm that worked fine. Weird  have used this exact code one time before on the mainviewcontroller and it worked fine. Im not sure why it dose not work now. weird.